# Search pattern % doesnt work in access

Tags: sql, debugging, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ansi-sql-92

In the table `trans` I have two such values `t_bar` and `t_pro`, and I want to find such values in the table. that start with `"t_"` So I`m using such query:

```
select trim(col)
from trans
where trim(col) like "t_%";
```

No rows are returned. However such query will return desired 2 rows:

```
select trim(col)
from trans
where trim(col) like "t_***";
```

What is wrong here?  I need to use %, because the real  situation more difficult.

Comment: `%` has no effect in ms-access. You should use `*` for pattern matching. Hence you get the results with the second query.

Comment: Do you get what you want with `ALike` instead of `Like`? ... `where trim(col) ALike "t_%"` If you want *t* followed by a literal underscore, do it this way: `where trim(col) ALike "t[_]%"`

Comment: @HansUp wow, fantastic, it works - but why?

Comment: `ALike` signals the db engine to expect ANSI wild cards (`%` and `_`) instead of the wild cards Access uses (`*` and `?`) in most situations.  Beware that for a query run from ADO/OleDb, Access expects ANSI wildcards in `Like` patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match any number of characters that start with `t_` you should use,

```
select trim(col)
from trans
where trim(col) like "t_*"
```

Comment: See also comments to the question from @HansUp re: `ALIKE` vs. `LIKE`.